Will this Ebike powerbank circuit work?
A noobie here. I'm making a powerbank for my ebike. The ebike that I have has a power supply that outputs 42 V 3 A. I'm trying to mimic that with my power bank so that I can plug the powerbank into the ebike. Look at circuit below. The "INPUT DC JACK" is used to charge the powerbank and the "OUT JACK" (constant volt (42 V) constant current (3 A)) will be plugged into my ebike charging port. I'm just not sure if this would work. I kind of made it fast and there are 100% dumb faults in it. The battery in the power bank is a 7S3P battery (21-29.4 V output, 44 A max output). Battery inside my ebike is 10S and has a BMS with a balancer in it. I would appreciate any help as I have very basic knowledge about electronics. Will this circuit that I made work?
Circuit:


What "100% dumb faults" do you see? I suspect one related to a diode...

What is wrong with the diode?

I would guess it is highly recommended to have a reverse polarity protection on the input and maybe also a TVS depending on how well you trust it. With the usual PMOS solution where drain is towards the input voltage, you can also add a zener between source and gate to get an over voltage protection feature. There should be example schematics elsewhere on this site.

It looks OK.
Generally, there's not need for that ideal diode because generally the charger doesn't discharge the battery while off.
The SoC meter based on bus voltage won't really tell you much because the voltage of Li-ion batteries changes more due to the current than the State of Charge.
Instead of a single-port BMS (as you've shown) consider instead a two-port one:

C- to the charger only
P- to the load only


The diode is there (I suspect) to stop battery voltage getting back to the power input (via the buck regulator, a natural path) and activating the power relay that selects the display.

I put the diode there because I don't want the voltage to go back through the buck regulator if I disconnect the power input as this will break it (and ofcourse because of the relay). The two-port bms is very smart but I already have a single port one...

I don't really understand why the SoC meter wouldn't work though. Am I missing something? How can I see the battery capacity then?

"why the SoC meter wouldn't work". Because, as I said "because the voltage of Li-ion batteries changes more due to the current than the State of Charge." You will see the reported SoC drop further when you accelerate more than when the battery is empty.

"How can I see the battery capacity then?" Not easily. It requires a "fuel gauge" circuit with in turn needs a current sensor. Not easy.

"I put the diode there because I don't want the voltage to go back through the buck regulator " It won't. The buck regulator is unidirectional: power can only go from the input to the output.
